# Set focus to a column filter in an Infragistics WebDataGrid

Tags: infragistics, webdatagrid

I am using an Infragistics NetAdvantage WebDataGrid with filtering set.

On page load, I would like to open the first filter’s textbox, and set the focus there, so that it is ready for the user to start typing the text with which to filter.

[image]

I have seen an example online of how to do this for the jQuery grid, but not for the WebDataGrid

I want something along the lines of:

```
         myWebDataGrid.Behaviors.Filtering.ColumnFilters[2].RuleTextNode.focus;
```

I am using  Infragistics35.Web.v11.2, Version=11.2.20112.2025

Answer (score 1):

To do this you can call enterEditMode on the filter row when your page loads, passing in the specific cell you want edit:

```
function enterEditFilter() {
    var grid = $find('<%= grid.ClientID %>');
    var filtering = grid.get_behaviors().get_filtering();
    var filterRow = filtering._row;
    var cell = filterRow.get_cellByColumnKey('Text');

    filtering.enterEditMode(cell);
}
```

Please note that to do this you have to be able to get access to the filter row. It doesn't appear that there is a way to access this through the public API so I use the private variable _row. This is not a recommended approach as that variable may change, so I suggest that you submit a new product idea to have the filter row added to the public API. You can do this on the following page:

http://ideas.infragistics.com/

Another thing to note is that the default filter type is "All" so you'll also want to change this.  You can do this by handling the client side filtering event and setting the rule there:

```
function grid_filtering(sender, eventArgs) {
    var filters = eventArgs.get_columnFilters();

    for (var i = 0; i < filters.length; i++) {
        var condition = filters[i].get_condition();
        if (condition.get_rule() === 0) {
            var columnType = filters[i].get_columnType();
            if (columnType == 'string') {
                condition.set_rule($IG.TextFilterRules.Equals);
            }
            else if (columnType == 'number') {
                condition.set_rule($IG.NumericFilterRules.Equals);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Var "grid" is null when "enterEditFilter()" is called from PageLoad.   
I tried calling "enterEditFilter()" from other events such as the wdg PageLoad, wdg DataBound , etc but could not get it to work.
Code works nicely when called from a html button click on the page, but I wanted it on PageLoad.  What should I try now?

Comment: When I created this example I tested it by calling my function in the body's onload client event and was able to get the grid without issue. My hunch is that somehow the logic for finding the grid isn't quite working for you, though I'd need to see more of your implementation to know what's going on. Could you provide more information about your setup? Or, if you prefer to submit a support case on the Infragistics website we can take the discussion there.